# Handling exceptions when using dependency injection in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, exception, dependency-injection

First of all, please excuse any typo as English is not my native language.

Let's say I want to use constructor injection in my application. So for example, I will have something like that:

```
public class FileDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    public MyData GetData()
    {
        // Get data from a file
    }
}

public class DatabaseDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    public MyData GetData()
    {
        // Get data from a database
    }
}

public class DataReader : IDataReader
{
    private IDataProvider dataProvider;

    public DataReader(IDataProvider dataProvider)
    {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public void OutputData()
    {
        MyData data = dataProvider.GetData();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", data.ToString());
    }
}
```

If I use constructor injection I have by definition no control nor idea about the concrete instance of the class implementing IDataProvider that will be injected into my DataReader class. Meaning that in my DataReader class I don't know what's going on in GetData method including the fact that I don't know if it may throw an exception or not and if so what kind of exception.

In my OutputData method, should I wrap my code into a try { } catch { } block and if so what exception should I catch? If I catch IOException or SQLException or actually *any* kind of exception means that I am preconceiving some ways IDataProvider may/should be implemented. I don't think it is good. I could also have an XMLDataProvider or NetworkResourceDataProvider injected. But at the same time I must handle exceptions at some point.

My question: What is the correct way of handling exception and logging what happens in an application using inversion of control in general and constructor injection more specifically? Also what is the correct way - if any - for throwing exceptions in a class that implements an interface?

--

Adding a precision to my question, I will not own the code that will implement IDataProvider so I can't even be sure that a custom exception, say `DataProviderException` will be thrown. Even if I write guidelines for developers to do so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion the concrete implementations of `IDataProvider` should catch the appropriate exceptions (I/O for file povider, SQL for DB provider) and raise another exception that communicates a general error getting the data, i.e. a `DataProviderException`. If needed you can store the original exception as the inner exception property so that info is not lost.

Doing it this way the `DataReader` consumer only has to handle this particular exception and is shielded from the details. That assumes the consumer has a way of handling the exception, i.e. a retry is possible.

Comment: Agreed. Your consumer class does not need to know what occurred. It could just grab a packaged exception with a common wrapper exception and if need to provide more info - like if the exception is recoverable or not - define it on your wrapper exception.

Comment: I thought about it but it will work only if I own the code that implements `IDataProvider` which is not the case. So I can't really be sure other developers will thrown an `DataProviderException`. I can still add some guidelines but I can't be sure they will be followed... I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Guillaume: Then there is not much useful that can be done and I agree with John Saunders: don't catch it if you can't handle it

Answer (score 7):

By definition, if you don't know how to handle an exception, then don't catch it. Period.

Comment: So where should exceptions be handled? Somewhere in my DI container? How can I know that something went wrong somewhere to warn user before crashing the application if need be for example.

Comment: Why is it the job of your DI container to warn users? Do you have a different container for Windows Forms vs. Web Forms? No? Then your container should have nothing to do with UI (like warning users). And what are you going to warn the user _about_? Will you be giving them any information they can use? Try not "handling" the exception at all, then see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

Let me start by saying your English is way better than my French, so t'inquietes pas de ca.

You're not going to do something special at this point in the code if an SQLException happens, right?

In general, you don't want to catch an exception until you know what you'd do with it. Exceptions generally serve to give developers a way to know what went wrong: that's why you get a stack trace to go along with them. So it's usually better to let them bubble up to a point just beneath the UI, where you can log them and gracefully tell the user that something unexpected happened.